# How do I make Win7 remember the size of windows?

Tags: windows-7, window

Every single time when I need to choose a file through an app via "Open..", the window neither remembers my listing preferences nor the window size I previously had.

Is there a way to force it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listing preferences and window size will be determined by the application and only remembered if the application developer thought to save the values between sessions.

I would be surprised if many developers bothered to save this information, so you are probably out of luck.

Comment: FML...[10charreq]